# A fortran timing issue I cannot understand

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote (for my class in Numerical Methods for Theoretical Physics) a very simple program for a Random Walk in dimension 2. Here it is:

```
program random_walk

implicit none

integer, parameter :: Nwalker = 1000000
integer, parameter :: Nstep   = 100
integer, parameter :: Nmeas   = 10

integer :: posx, posy, move

integer :: is, im, iw
real    :: start_time, stop_time

double precision, dimension(Nmeas) :: dist, r2
real :: rnd

do im = 1, Nmeas
    dist(im) = im*Nstep
    r2(im)   = 0.0
end do

call cpu_time(start_time)
do iw = 1, Nwalker
    posx = 0
    posy = 0
    do im = 1, Nmeas
        do is = 1, Nstep
            call random_number(rnd)
            move = 4*rnd
            if (move == 0) posx = posx + 1
            if (move == 1) posy = posy + 1
            if (move == 2) posx = posx - 1
            if (move == 3) posy = posy - 1
        end do
        r2(im) = r2(im) + posx**2 + posy**2
    end do
end do
r2 = r2 / Nwalker
call cpu_time(stop_time)
do im = 1, Nmeas
    print '(f8.6, "   ", f8.6)', log(dist(im)), log(r2(im))
end do
print '("Time = ", f6.3, " seconds")', stop_time - start_time
end program
```

In the end it should print 10 rows 2 columns: first column is the logarithm of "time" (number of steps), second column is the logarithm of the average squared distance from the origin. The second column "on average" should be equal to the first. So far so good, the program is working well, results are very reasonable. But here the problem; on my macbookpro (2,7 GHz Intel Core i7, compiler gfortran 7.1.0, optimization -O2) it tooks on average more than 20 seconds to run. But if I comment out these lines:

```
! do im = 1, Nmeas
!    print '(f8.6, "   ", f8.6)', log(dist(im)), log(r2(im))
! end do
```

which are beyond of "stop_time" computation, the result is that the running time is... less than 6 seconds!?

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a typical thing to observe. People hit this when they create artificial computations which only test performance and do not create a useful result. When the result is not printed, the compiler can recognize that it does not need the result for the program output and may completely omit the computation.

To examine it you can add the `-fdump-tree-optimized` flag to get a special source form called GIMPLE and you can compare the output for those two variants of the source code. It writes the output to a file called `yourfilename.f90.something.optimized`. I can indeed see a big part missing. Basically the whole `r2` array and the operations with it are optimized out. You can also compare the generated assembly if you know that better.

Comment: That's quite a lesson for me, thanks. In the meanwhile i rewrote the program in C (very simply, just a stupid line-by-line translation of the original program) and the running time is about 6.8 seconds with or without printing out the result. Does it mean that C overperform fortran by a factor of 3 in time for such a simple computational task? It really comes out like a surprise to me.

Comment: Generally it does not. But without the code no-one can say. You can create a new question about it but you will have to supply a lot of details. Both codes, measurement results, try to use the same random number generator or no random numbers...

Comment: Yes. Sometimes I'm able to do such stupid things that after a second I cannot understand how is it possible... I was wrongly assuming that random number generators had about the same performance, but it is not true, obviously. I wrote from scratch in both languages a really simple congruential generator, identical (just a translation), nothing to be used in a serius context (and in fact "physical" results are just junk), but i obtain the same results to machine precision in C and in Fortran, but Fortran code executes something like 25% faster. I feel better now. Thanks again.