# Complexity for accessing fortran array in a loop

Tags: arrays, fortran, time-complexity

Recently I'm investigating the complexity of accessing fortran array. Thanks to the comments, here I include complete examples.

```
program main

    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: mp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,307)
    integer, parameter :: Np=10, rep=100
    integer*8, parameter :: Ng(7) = (/1E3,1E4,1E5,1E6,1E7,1E8,1E9/)
    real(mp), allocatable :: x(:)
    real(mp) :: time1, time2
    integer*8 :: i,j,k, Ngj 
    real(mp) :: temp
    integer :: g

    ! print to screen
    print *, 'calling program main'

    do j=1,SIZE(Ng)   !test with different Ng

        !initialization with each Ng. Don't count for complexity.
        Ngj = Ng(j)
        if(ALLOCATED(x)) DEALLOCATE(x)
        ALLOCATE(x(Ngj))
        x = 0.0_mp

        !!===This is the part I want to check the complexity===!!
        call CPU_TIME(time1)

        do k=1,rep
            do i=1,Np
               call RANDOM_NUMBER(temp)
               g = floor( Ngj*temp ) + 1 

              x( g ) = x( g ) + 1.0_mp
            end do
        end do

        call CPU_TIME(time2)

        print *, 'Ng: ',Ngj,(time2-time1)/rep, '(sec)'

    end do

    ! print to screen
    print *, 'program main...done.'

contains

end program
```

I thought in the beginning its complexity is O(Np). But this is the time measurement for Np=10:

```
 calling program main
 Ng:                  1000   7.9000000000000080E-007 (sec)
 Ng:                 10000   4.6000000000000036E-007 (sec)
 Ng:                100000   3.0999999999999777E-007 (sec)
 Ng:               1000000   4.8000000000001171E-007 (sec)
 Ng:              10000000   7.3999999999997682E-007 (sec)
 Ng:             100000000   2.1479999999999832E-005 (sec)
 Ng:            1000000000   4.5719999999995761E-005 (sec)
 program main...done.
```

This Ng-dependency is very slow and appears only for very large Ng, but is not dominated when increasing Np; increasing Np just multiplies a constant factor on that time scaling.
Also, it seems that the scaling slope increases when I use more complicated subroutines rather than random number.
Computing temp and g was verified to be independent of Ng.
There are two questions with this situation:

1. Based on comments, this kind of measurement does not only include intended arithmetic operations but also costs related to memory cache or compiler. Would there be a more correct way to measure the complexity?
2. Concerning the issues mentioned in the comments, like memory cache, page missing, or compiler, are they inevitable as the array size increases? or is there any way to avoid these costs?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. You are not showing  the complete code, see [mcve]. You must show the complete.code, including the time measurement and your compiler commands. It is possible, that the compiler optimizes out your code, because the resuůt is not uses. We have duplicates bout that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583729/a-fortran-timing-issue-i-cannot-understand

Comment: It is also possible that I do not understand what the numbers you show mean, maybe it is the time for one iteration. But you must tell that explicitly and illustratethat with your code! See also [ask]. Do not forget there is not just the CPU, there is also memory and caches and accessing them costs various amounts of time.

Comment: VladimirF is almost certainly right, you are seeing the increasing cost due to cache and possibly page misses. But I'm afraid to say without a clearer explanation with a full program it is impossible to say for certain. And don't use the non-standard, potential non-portable real*8 - use kinds instead which you clearly know about because you use _dp on your constants

Comment: Bear in mind that the whole structure of big-O and asymptotic complexity is based on a theoretical model of a computer in which trifling concerns such as cache size, the time-uniformity of memory access, and a whole bunch of other engineering concerns are simply assumed away.  Observing that the loop timing goes from `~0.0s` to `~0.0s` as `Ng` goes through 3 orders of magnitude tells us something about the computer it is running on, and nothing at all about the order of complexity of the operation.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the comments. I just replaced with a complete example.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for addressing other potential issues. It may sound general, but would there be a way to measure the order of operation complexity, excluding those other factors? or a way to investigate what specific part scales with array size?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do I understand this complexity? What is the cost that I missed to
>      account for? I guess the cost for accessing to an element in
>      an array does depend on the size of the array. A few stack overflow
>      posts say that array accessing costs only O(1) for some languages. I
>      think it should also hold for fortran, but I do not know why that is
>      not the case.

Aside from what you ask more or less explicitly to the program (performing the loop, getting random numbers, etc), a number of events occur such as the loading of the runtime environment and input/output processing. To make useful timings, you must either perfectly isolate the code to time or arrange for the actual computation to take a lot more time than the rest of the code.

> 2. Is there any way to avoid this cost?

This is in reply 1 :-)

Now, for a solution: I completed your example and let it run for hundreds of millions of iterations. See below:

```
program time_random

  integer, parameter :: rk = selected_real_kind(15)
  integer, parameter :: Ng = 100
  real(kind=rk), dimension(Ng) :: x = 0
  real(kind=rk) :: temp
  integer :: g, Np

  write(*,*) 'Enter number of loops'
  read(*,*) Np

  do i=1,Np
     call RANDOM_NUMBER(temp)
     g = floor( Ng*temp ) + 1
     x(g) = x(g) + 1
  end do

  write(*,*) x

end program time_random
```

I compiled it with `gfortran -O3 -Wall -o time_random time_random.f90` and time it with the `time` function from bash. Beware that this is very crude (and explains why I made the number of iterations so large). It is also very simple to set up:

```sh
for ii in 100000000 200000000 300000000 400000000 500000000 600000000
do
time echo $ii | ./time_random 1>out
done
```

You can now collect the timings and observe a linear complexity. My computer reports 14 ns per iteration.

Remarks:

1. I used `selected_real_kind` to specify the real kind.
2. I write `x` after the loop to ensure that the loop is not optimized away.

Comment: I think the question is how the time scales with Ng, not with Np - though I agree it's not entirely clear

Comment: Thanks for the comment @IanBush indeed the timings in the question are a function of `Ng`.